# Replace special characters on a set with

Tags: jquery, replace

I have the following set of characters:

```
var arr = '%^&*()!#<>?[]{}\ /'
```

I need to replace any of them of it is found in the on `keyUp();` event  using the following code:

```
 $("input").keyup(function (e) {
      var arr = {'%^&*()!#<>?[]{}\ /'};
      $(this).val($(this).val().replace('#####', ''));
 });
```

but I don't know what I must put as the first argument of `.replace()` function

Answer (score 0):

You can use `evtobj.keyCode` to get ASCII of the key pressed. Then you can check it against your array (which stores ASCII values and not characters) and use the character value of ASCII matched as the first argument in your replace function.